# Rspec POST Test not passing. Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This POST create test is not working. It should redirect to reports_path, but it does not work.

```
describe "POST #create" do
    let(:report) { assigns(:report) }
    let(:test_option) { create(:option) }
    let(:test_student) { create(:student) }

    context "when valid" do
      before(:each) do
        post :create, params: {
          report: attributes_for(:report, student: test_student,
          report_options_attributes: [build(:report_option).attributes]
          )
        }
      end

      it "should redirect to reports_path" do
        expect(response).to redirect_to reports_path
      end
```

My params are set like this:

```
def report_params
    params.require(:report).permit(:student,
      report_options_attributes: [:id, :option, :note, :_destroy]
    )
end
```

Controller:

```
def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)
    if @report.save
      redirect_to reports_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Report model:

```
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, dependent: :delete
  has_many :report_options, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_options, allow_destroy: true
end
```

ReportOption model:

```
class ReportOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :report, optional: true
end
```

I am passing the correct params in the test, but I really do not know what is going wrong..

Comment: Sure, I also posted the models that I am using

Comment: Sure @ArunKumar

Comment: I guess your test is not creating a `report` object. So, it renders the `new` view again which is 200 and not a redirect.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it is not creating.. But can you see what is wrong with it? There are exactly the same params of the report_params. @ArunKumar

Comment: Add `puts response.inspect` before the expectation and inspect the result. That should give an idea of what's happening in the test.

Comment: Lots of things on display @ArunKumar

Comment: Why don't you add `debugger` before `if @report.save` in your controller and check `@report.valid?`. It will return false if any validation fails.

Comment: @ArunKumar, I tried the answer bellow and it worked. Do you have any idea of why it works passing the ids, not the objects?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh it says false. How do I check what is going wrong with the validations? I am passing a student using a factory to the params.

Comment: Do I need to pass the params exactly as they are in DB? Is that why passing student_id in the params works and passing the object student does not work?

Comment: You can see what failed by typing `@report.errors.full_messages` right after you call `@report.valid?`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh it gave me this: `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fb70a811ed8 @base=#<Report id: nil, student_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:student=>["must exist"]}, @details={:student=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
(byebug) @report.errors.full_messages
["Student must exist"]`. I am passing the student as an object although it is saying that `student_id` is `nil`. Should I pass the params exactly as they are in the DB table?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. I fixed it passing just the ids in the params like that:

```
def report_params
    params.require(:report).permit(:student_id,
      report_options_attributes: [:id, :option_id, :note, :_destroy]
    )
end
```

Don't know if it will work for you. You also need to change the `student: test_student` to `student_id: test_student.id` inside your `before(:each)`.

Comment: but do you know why It is necessary to change? I did the same with other models without nested attributes and worked.

Comment: It worked.. but I still do not know why passing the object, not its id, does not work..

Comment: As your controller does not create a student, you need to passa the ID.